# Error message in nova schedule

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, devstack, nova-scheduler

i tried to start 5 instance on my "litle cloud". I have one controller node (tb22) with nova-api and compute. An i have one compute node (tb23).
I get an error message in nova-schedule:

> 2014-07-09 13:00:23.858 ERROR nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler
>   [req-f699a7d3-e3de-40e4-b291-9ae972c7d8f9 admin demo] [instance:
>   55febf3d-1d56-4381-a6ca-b4b3b37e92e0] Error from last host: tb23 (node
>   tb23): [u'Traceback (most recent call last):\n', u'  File
>   "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1305, in
>   _build_instance\n    set_access_ip=set_access_ip)\n', u'  File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 393, in
>   decorated_function\n    return function(self, context, *args,
>   **kwargs)\n', u'  File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1717, in *spawn\n    LOG.exception(*(\'Instance failed to spawn\'),
>   instance=instance)\n', u'  File
>   "/opt/stack/nova/nova/openstack/common/excutils.py", line 68, in
>   **exit**\n    six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)\n', u'  File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1714, in _spawn\n
>   block_device_info)\n', u'  File
>   "/opt/stack/nova/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 2262, in spawn\n
>   write_to_disk=True)\n', u'  File
>   "/opt/stack/nova/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 3447, in to_xml\n 
>   disk_info, rescue, block_device_info)\n', u'  File
>   "/opt/stack/nova/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 3263, in
>   get_guest_config\n    flavor)\n', u'  File
>   "/opt/stack/nova/nova/virt/libvirt/vif.py", line 384, in get_config\n 
>   _("Unexpected vif_type=%s") % vif_type)\n', u'NovaException: Unexpected vif_type=binding_failed\n']

Has anybody an idea what the fault is?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is error is caused by configuration mistake in

```
/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini
```

Fix

Edit `/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini`  on both compute and network node

Change `tunnel_type = gre` to `tunnel_types = gre`

**Restart these services  in network node**

service openvswitch-switch restart

￼service neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent restart

service neutron-l3-agent restart

service neutron-dhcp-agent restart

service neutron-metadata-agent restart

**Restart these services  in compute node**

service openvswitch-switch restart

service nova-compute restart

service neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent restart